# Problema al realizar conexión sql con java netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Estoy teniendo un problema con la conexión de **SSMS-2017** a mi aplicación hecha en Java. Tengo creada una clase Conexión con el siguiente código:

```java
    public class Conexion {
    private static Connection conexion;
    private static final String usuario = "sa";
    private static final String contraseña = "123";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba";
    
    public static Connection abrirConexion(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);
        }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conexion;
    }
    
    public static void cerrarConexion(){
        try{
            if(!conexion.isClosed()){
                conexion.close();
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

He descargado el driver de conexión y además para hacer la prueba de conectividad creé una clase Main con el siguiente. código:

```java
    public class Prueba {
    
    public static void main(String... args){
        Connection conexion = Conexion.abrirConexion();
        if(conexion != null){
            System.out.println("Conexión Exitosa");
            Conexion.cerrarConexion();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Falló Conexión");
        }
    }
}
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente. error:

```
    Falló Conexión
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se pudo realizar la 
    conexión TCP/IP al host localhost, puerto 1433. Error: "connect timed out. 
    Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay una instancia de 
    SQL Server ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las conexiones TCP/IP en el 
    puerto y compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando las conexiones TCP 
    en el puerto.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2369)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:551)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1963)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at ConexionSQL.Conexion.abrirConexion(Conexion.java:17)
    at ConexionSQL.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:10)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Quisiera que por favor me puedan brindar una ayuda a este problema. Muchas Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Tal cual te dice el error. Revisa el firewall en el servidor con la bd, revisa que las conexiones remotas estén habilitadas.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder e desactivado el firewall y las conexiones remotas están habilitadas pero igual sigo presentando el mismo problema. También e configurado el Sql Server Configuration Manager

Comment: `Class.forName` ya no es necesario, hace tiempo que JDBC simplificó la forma de conectar. Intenta creando la cadena de conexión en una sola variable, por ejemplo: `String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba;user=sa;password=123";`  y luego para conectar sólo hay que hacer esto: `try { conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url); //resto del código } catch ... { ... }` [Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-ver15). En cualquier caso debes verificar todos los puntos que indica el mensaje.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder. Acabo de probar la conexión con mysql y todo bien, el problema es solo al conectar con sql server. Sigo buscando soluciones

Comment: Estás seguro de que el servidor está corriendo? Qué ese es el puerto correcto? Este error está indicándote que no se encuentra el servicio de MSSQLServer en esa ip y/o en ese puerto, o que por algún motivo no puede acceder a esa IP. No está relacionado con credenciales erróneas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas amigos acabo de solucionar el problema que tenía con la conexión a sql server lo hice de esta manera:
Primero había habilitado el protocolo TCP/IP y agregado el pueto 1433 en SQLServer Configuration Manager tal y como está en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero seguía presentando el problema con la conexión. Como ven me aparece una lista de IPs, para solucionar el inconveniente lo que hice fue agregar en IPAll en TCP Port el puerto 1433 y borrar lo que había hecho en la imagen anterior, luego reiniciar sql server, para después probar la conexión y listo conexión exitosa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]